# Where'd my UTF-8 locale go?

Tags: centos, locale

Running `yum update` in the centos7 docker container seems to remove the UTF-8 locale.

```
~/ ]$ docker run -it centos:centos7 /bin/bash
root@d27a0a1d3714 /]# locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
[root@d27a0a1d3714 /]# yum -y update
...
< bunch of updates >
...
[root@d27a0a1d3714 /]# locale -a
C
POSIX
```

Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this expected?

Most likely, you did not have the `en_US.utf8` locale in `/etc/locale.gen`, and thus when something triggered reconfiguration of locales (i.e., `locale-gen`), you lost the `en_US.utf8` locale. How your system got in that state is anyone's guess. Make sure all the locales you want are in `/etc/locale.gen`.